# How to move viewcontroller to front?

Tags: swift

I want to move PlayVideoViewController to the top of other view controllers like the picture. Please help!!!!!

[image]

Comment: share some code that you've written

Comment: I would suggest to describe the problem and the reason why would you do that.

Comment: playerVideoViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "PlayVideo", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "playVideoSBID") as? PlayVideoViewController
        
        self.view = playerVideoViewController?.view
        
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        
        self.window?.addSubview(self.view!)
        self.window?.bringSubview(toFront: self.view!)

Comment: I wrote that in app delegate. I do it because I want to make a floating view controller like youtube

Comment: When I perform segue to open another view controller it hide that my playvideo view controller

Comment: add all details and code to question instead of posting them in comment, that will help people in helping you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a new view controller and set it as a child view controller. 
You can create a container view in which that controller will be added.

```
self.childViewControllers.first?.view.removeFromSuperview()
self.childViewControllers.first?.removeFromParentViewController()
self.containerView.addSubview(controller.view)
self.addChildViewController(controller)
```

Do remember to add a container view